# Prestashop 1.6 - Creating video section in admin to manage and display in fornt-end

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I am using prestashop version 1.6 in localhost. I need to add our own video section  in admin / back office to manage and display those videos in a separate page in front end. For example, about us and term and conditions pages like that.

I have developed my own module upto configuration section of the module. Now i need to add my own form fields like title, embedcode and submit button. I dont know how to add our own form fields with "helper class" of prestashop. Also i have read the documentation but could not able to get. Can you guide me please ? Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Here is my code:
videomodule.php:

```
          <?php 

          if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
            exit;
          class VideoModule extends Module
          {
            public function __construct()
              {
                $this->name = 'videomodule';
                $this->tab = 'video';
                $this->version = 1.0;
                $this->author = 'Dinesh Kumar';
                $this->need_instance = 0;
                $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_); 
                $this->bootstrap = true;

                parent::__construct();

                $this->displayName = $this->l('Video Module');
                $this->description = $this->l('It is really an awesome experience');
                $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');
            Configuration::updateValue('video', serialize(array(true, true, false)));
                if (!Configuration::get('videomodule'))      
                        $this->warning = $this->l('No name provided');

                //  echo Configuration::get('videoid');
              }
          public function getContent()
          {
              $output = null;

              if (Tools::isSubmit('submit'.$this->name))
              {
                  $my_module_name = strval(Tools::getValue('videomodule'));
                  if (!$my_module_name
                    || empty($my_module_name)
                    || !Validate::isGenericName($my_module_name))
                      $output .= $this->displayError($this->l('Invalid Configuration value'));
                  else
                  {
                      Configuration::updateValue('videomodule', $my_module_name);
                      $output .= $this->displayConfirmation($this->l('Settings updated'));
                  }
              }
              return $output.$this->displayForm();
          }

          public function displayForm()
          {
              // Get default language
              $default_lang = (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');

              // Init Fields form array
              $fields_form[0]['form'] = array(
                  'legend' => array(
                      'title' => $this->l('Settings'),
                  ),
                  'input' => array(
                      array(
                          'type' => 'text',
                          'label' => $this->l('Configuration value'),
                          'name' => 'videomodule',
                          'size' => 20,
                          'required' => true
                      )
                  ),

                  'submit' => array(
                      'title' => $this->l('Save'),
                      'class' => 'button'
                  )
              );



              $helper = new HelperForm();

          // Module, Token and currentIndex
          $helper->module = $this;
          $helper->name_controller = $this->name;
          $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
          $helper->currentIndex = AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name;

          // Language
          $helper->default_form_language = $default_lang;
          $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = $default_lang;

          // title and Toolbar
          $helper->title = $this->displayName;
          $helper->show_toolbar = true;        // false -> remove toolbar
          $helper->toolbar_scroll = true;      // yes - > Toolbar is always visible on the top of the screen.
          $helper->submit_action = 'submit'.$this->name;
          $helper->toolbar_btn = array(
              'save' =>
              array(
                  'desc' => $this->l('Save'),
                  'href' => AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name.'&save'.$this->name.
                  '&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
              ),
              'back' => array(
                  'href' => AdminController::$currentIndex.'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
                  'desc' => $this->l('Back to list')
             )
          );

          // Load current value
          $helper->fields_value['videomodule'] = Configuration::get('videomodule');

          return $helper->generateForm($fields_form);
          }

            public function install()
            {
              if (Shop::isFeatureActive())
                Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_ALL);

              if (!parent::install() ||
                !$this->registerHook('leftColumn') ||
                !$this->registerHook('header') ||
                !Configuration::updateValue('videomodule', 'my friend')

              )
                return false;

              return true;
            }


            public function uninstall()
            {
              if (!parent::uninstall() ||
                !Configuration::deleteByName('videomodule')
              )
                return false;

              return true;
            }

            public function hookLeftColumn( $params )
            {
              global $smarty;
              return $this->display(__FILE__,'videomodule.tpl');
            }

          public function hookRightColumn($params)
            {
                return $this->hookLeftColumn($params);
            }


          }
```

Comment: give some code what you have tried?

Comment: Hi Dinesh and welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you *writing* software or *using* software? If you are *writing* software. can you please show us the relevant code (please edit your question and add it there, don't just reply). If you are *using* software, than Stack Overflow is probably the wrong site for this question, and you will have better help from our sister site SuperUser (get to it by clicking "StackExchange" at the top left of this page)

Comment: @ketan: I have edited my question by adding my code which i have tried. Upto this i have tried.., welcome for all replies.

Comment: @ Taryn East : Writing software..,